# How to create a tweet to button inside my tweet

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2, twitter-card, twitter-button

I saw a tweet that had a button at its bottom that said "Tweet #xxx" and when it was clicked it opened a pre-filled tweet for me to just click and send its way.

This is on twitter.com website directly. Not on another website.

I have been searching how to do something like that and to no avail. Can someone send me where I can find a tutorial for this?

[image]

This is the interface I am getting when clicking Tweet#BuMamaBenden button.

[image]